# Nginx proxy_pass, limit active concurrent connections

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, nextcloud

I have a service running in low end machine (behind `Nginx`) and the CPU performance is rather weak. One of the API needs a lots of CPU time, so it's required to limit the max concurrent requests. But if the request is cached, it can response much faster.

What I want to do is limit the max concurrent connections sent to the backend service for the certain API. I researched `limit_req` and `limit_conn`, but neither of them satisfies my case. `limit_req` may cause high load (too many miss) or low load (when most of the requests are cached), it is not easy to determine the value. While `limit_conn` will drop the rest of the requests (I want them to be queued).

Currently, I'm using apache2 `mpm` module, but it limits all the requests.

Is it possible to make Nginx keep max connections and make the others wait?

Answer (score 0):

### Nginx Cache Based

If many of the requests try to access the exact same data, then you can use the [locking mechanism](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?&_ga=2.78950612.1994112989.1582250441-214521564.1581120181#proxy_cache_lock) to at least prevent overloading the server when really not useful.

```
proxy_cache_lock on
```

I do not know of another solution for your situation. Holding requests when N were already sent to the service does not seem to be an option by default. If you had multiple such servers, you could setup nginx as a load balancer, but that's a quite different concept.

### Apache2 Request Based

With Apache you can specify the [maximum number of client connections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) that can be made at once. By setting this value to a very small number, including 1, it will automatically queue additional requests.

```
MaxRequestWorkers 1
```

(In older versions, before 2.3.13, use `MaxClients`)

This is a server configuration so all connections will be affected. Therefore it is important that you run a separate instance for that specific service and route all access through that one specific Apache2 server.

```
          O  Internet
          |
          v
+-------------------+
|                   |   proxy based on URL or such
|  Main HTTP Server +---------------+
|                   |               |
+---------+---------+               |
          |                         v
          |               +-----------------------------------+
          v               |                                   |
+-------------------+     |  Apache with MaxRequestWorkers=1  |
|                   |     |                                   |
|  Main Services    |     +---------+-------------------------+
|                   |               |
+-------------------+               |
                                    v
                        +--------------------------+
                        |                          |
                        |  Slow Service Here       |
                        |                          |
                        +--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit. It seems like proxy_cache is not designed for this purpose, and cannot realize the requirements. It limits one query to the origin server, but the others will fetch the same result.

Comment: @Newnius Ah, yes. Sorry I thought that you were asking about access that would be cached. If not cached, then it wouldn't help, indeed. I'm afraid I do not have an answer. I think most technologies would be used to distribute your requests to multiple backends instead of stalling them.

Comment: Yes, I know my situation is abnormal. The truth is that the performance of my NAS is very poor, so I need need the maxconn when rendering thumbnails, or the server would stall for several minutes.

Comment: @Newnius Okay. Got it (although I didn't test...) I think you can add a proxy which hits another HTTP server where you limit the number of workers. I do not know about Nginx, but I would imagine it has a similar limitation. I show how to setup Apache to limit the number of connections to just 1. I hope that works for you!